# Error when I delete instances in the django panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a duplicate function in order to create a new and equal instance from an other.
But when I try to delete the instance the next error appears:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

What must I do in my function for to solve it?

My duplicate function is:

```
def duplicate(scn):
    id_original = scn.id
    scn.id = Scenario.objects.order_by('id')[Scenario.objects.all().count()-1].id + 1
    scn.name = scn.name + '_dup'
    scn.save() #ahora scn es el nuevo
    scn_original = Scenario.objects.filter(id=id_original)[0]
    return None
```

Comment: It means something is refering to your object, and you thus can not remove the object from the database.

Comment: Maybe something like a field of type models.OneToOneField ?